# FileIO from ArrayList

Tags: c#, file-io, collections, arraylist

I have been learning about the collections namespace in C# so have been doing some little self-made projects to learn.

I have made a car race app where you enter in the name, car and place of the racer this is then stored in an array list. I can extract the contents of my array list onto the console window but I would like to know how I can write and save it to a text file (kindof like a mini database).

I know that every element stored in an array list is stored as an object therefore casting is needed to extract them to their appropriate types.

Here is how my array list handles the inputs:

```
class People
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }

    public ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

    public void ShowList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + myList[i] + "\n|");
        }          
    }

    public void AddToList()
    {          
        myList.Add("Name: " + Name + " Car: " + Car + " Place: " + Place);            
    }

}
```

Here is how I am trying to save myList to a text file:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Keil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CarRacingArrList\racers.txt"))
        {
            file.WriteLine(person.myList.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I added the ToString() method to cast all the elements inside myList to a string.

The output I get into my textfile is this: System.Collections.ArrayList

Is the the result of invalid casting or just something I have missed out?

Thankyou

Comment: You need to write each element separately. Btw, do use [generic collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172181(v=vs.110).aspx) (introduced in .NET 2.0) instead or `ArrayList`. You will find that there is rarely a need to use an `ArrayList` to store a list of objects.

Comment: Additionally, if the purpose of this code is to persist data to disk so that you can load it back later, look into [various serialization alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET (e.g. `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`) because it will solve many problems you need to solve manually otherwise.

Comment: As a side note: You may want to figure out how to make a person class so that you just have a `List<Person> People` or a `List<Person>` in your People class. The reason being Name, Car, and Place all seem to be properties of a person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do:

```
file.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList.OfType<string>()));
```

Or without `StreamWriter`:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   File.WriteAllLines("path", myList.OfType<string>());
}
```

Calling `ToString` on `ArrayList` is giving you the type name because that's the default behaviour of `ToString`, if the type doesn't override `ToString` method, the type name is returned by default.

Apart from that do not use `ArrayList`, use generic `List<T>` for type-safety and for many other benefits...

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop through all items of the array to write them all:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Keil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CarRacingArrList\racers.txt"))
{
    foreach(var item in myList)
        file.WriteLine(var.ToString());
}
```